# Backbone marionette and posting to an asp.net web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, post

Not wrapping my brain around this concept at all.  I've got a backbone marionette app that has a chat component.  All working well.

Each time a user hits the send button on a message, SignalR delivers it.  All that is good.  I also want to, however, after the message is delivered, submit the message to a web service written in asp.net VB by another developer.  That web service persists the message to his SQL server db.  I get that backbone models and asp.net Web API's are a natural fit.  But the other app is a standard asp.net webforms app, not a Web API.

My old Adobe Flex chat app talked to this web service very easily.  Was cake.  As I rewrite this Flex app as a backbone marionette app I'm missing how, conceptually, to post the chat messages to the persistence service. When I search for something like "asp.net ajax post web service" I get lots of stuff on the server-side control, ScriptManager.  Not applicable in a backbone app I would think.

I thought something like below might work, but I get an error deep inside jQuery, "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."

What is the conceptual misunderstanding I'm having here?

```
            var url = "http://mydomain.com/thesevice.asmx/theoperation";
            var formData = {userid: userid, message: msg};
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //data - response from server
                    console.log("Successfully posted chat msg to service...");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("theoperation error: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptual misunderstanding is that you don't post the messages to the service from the client.  The service in question is on another domain.  There are cross domain issues when posting from the browser.  Should post from the server side code that is handling the chat routing.